# Detect when a user clicks file download link

Tags: files

I Have a view that outputs nodes, and also a link to download files that are attached to these nodes. I'd like to know when a user clicks one of these links, so that I can log the event.

All attached files are files in drupal's public file directory, inside a directory at sites/default/files

Is there good approach for detecting a click or file download in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Module [Track da files](https://www.drupal.org/project/track_da_files) (despite its goofy name) tracks both public and private files. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... enables the possibility to track how much visitors are viewing files on site.
>
> Every link to a file can be configured to be tracked. Then, a record is registered each time a visitor access the file from this specific link.

Comment: Thanks, track_da_files looks interesting. In this case, I am excluding, then rewriting the link to the file, so I need to look into how I might adjust the view to use the field formatters provided by tdf.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how/why are you rewriting the link to the file?

Comment: These are practice worksheets for lessons, so I'm rewriting the url as a link that always displays "Practice", regardless of the actual file name.

Comment: Oh, okay, so the path itself isn't changing, just the label?

Comment: Right. My saying "rewriting" wasn't really clear, but I was talking about the "rewrite results" feature in views.